# Capturing text between square brackets in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I need some way of capturing the text between square brackets. So for example, the following string:

`[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].`

Could be used to create the following array:

```
Array ( 
     [0] => [This] 
     [1] => [test] 
     [2] => [eat] 
     [3] => [shorts] 
)
```

I have the following regex, `/\[.*?\]/` but it only captures the first instance, so:

```
Array ( [0] => [This] )
```

How can I get the output I need? Note that the square brackets are NEVER nested, so that's not a concern.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Matches all strings with brackets:

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

If You want strings without brackets:

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Alternative, slower version of matching without brackets (using "*" instead of "[^]"):

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [eat] my [shorts].';
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: And if you want the strings between the brackets: preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/",$text,$matches);

Comment: @GertVandeVen: Backslashes required. 
preg_match_all("/\\[(.*?)\\]/",$text,$matches). Probably web removed Yours ;)

Comment: @GertVandeVen Weirdly, I now get the following: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [This] [1] => [test] [2] => [eat] [3] => [shorts] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => This [1] => test [2] => eat [3] => shorts ) )`

Comment: Yes, you will get the full matches, and the ones between () separately.

Comment: Basically you can now show: print_r($matches[1]); which will only get you the ones between brackets.

Comment: @GertVandeVen Yeah, that's what I've done, I just wasn't expecting it. All good though, thanks!

Comment: it would be best if your code is `preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Updated for a litter faster version. It should be around 0.5 second faster in 1 milion matches.

Comment: Why do you not show how to use it for other characters? { } ( ) etc.

Comment: i want use with in { } or  ( )  how i do it ?

Comment: Can you update a regex to support multiline content?, currently its working for single line only

Comment: How to get result in matches[0] without brackets? did anyone solved it?