# php: searching for squared brackets and get content of them

Tags: php, regex

I just need to check a string (php) for squared brackets. If there are squared bracket, I want to get it's content for further processing.

**String**:

```
This is just a
[needle]
example
```

As there is a squared bracket, I want to get it's value, which is "needle" in this example.
Now I will get some value for needle in a SQL-DB and replace the bracket with that.

i.e. keyword "needle" will get the value "great" out of the DB, so the result would be:

```
This is just a
great
example
```

I tried to use str_replace

```
$content= str_replace('[]', '',$content);
```

but this is the wrong approach, as I first need to check for the value and send a SQL-query...

**Update:** I think the linked thread ([Capturing text between square brackets in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php))  has a different question. As I don't just get the hits, but process these hits by replacing them. Therefore the mentioned function `preg_replace_callback` is the best solution.

Comment: The best function for this would be [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) - `preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/m", $text, $matches);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php

Comment: And if you want to substitute their [content], `preg_replace_callback()` might be worth investigating too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` to find the word inside the `[]`:

```
preg_match('/\[[^\]]+\]/', $content, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Then use `$match[0]` in your query.  Then you can use `preg_replace` in the same manner.