# Regex for breaking down Polynomial Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to break down a mathematic expression into pieces and I was trying to use the Regex `/\([^)]+\)/` to do the trick ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php)). But reading that answer, I understood that this Regex will be searching for the first closing parenthesis **)** to finish, giving me trouble when handling, for instance:

```
(2*x^2 + 5*x - (2*x - 3)^(1/2))/(1 + x)
^                      ^      ^
START                IGNORE FINISH
```

Since I'm not really good with coming up with Regex, I'm wondering if I should handle this with `strpos`, `substr` and `str_replace` or is there a different Regex to apply to preg_match_all and get the correct set of parenthesis?

*Note: This function will be recursive in order to solve inner parenthesis.*

EDIT:

My expected output in this case:

```
$array = null;
$expression = '(2*x^2 + 5*x - (2*x - 3)^(1/2))/(1 + x)';
$expression = str_replace(' ', '', $expression);
preg_match_all('MAGIC EXPRESSION HERE', , $array);
print_r($array);

// Output
array(
    [0] => (2*x^2+5*x-(2*x-3)^(1/2))
    [1] => (1+x)
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I swear I see you on every regex related question, haha

Comment: I added the expected output in the main text.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codehackit.blogspot.ca/2011/08/expression-parser-in-php.html

Comment: also give credits to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12455760/3297613) guy also..

Comment: May i know the reason for reopen vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match the nested parenthesis a [recursive](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) attempt could be:

```
\((?:[^)(]|(?R))*\)
```

At `(?R)` the pattern is pasted from start. Same like `(?0)`

See [example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uL4yB5/2); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: It works perfectly, sadly I find it so hard to understand.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Might want to see the link, that I provided from [rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) or [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) has also a nice tutorial :)