# How to extract a value between square brackets in php

Tags: php

I am writing some code that expects to receive a block of html which is always going to include the following:

```
var code = [39.474, -0.3548];
```

The value between the square brackets is always going to be different. How could I extract the value between the square brackets using php?

I should probably point out that I am parsing a block of HTML to php that includes js aswell.

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression like

```
preg_match_all('/\\[(.*?)\\]/', $your_string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The array `$matches[1]` then will contain your values.

Comment: i got one more post which gives u multiple bracket values if u have https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104517/4758038

Answer (score 0):

If the Javascript array format will be kept constant (always two components and a space after ','), you can use `/(?:\[)(.*)[,][ ](.*)(?:\])/` regex to extract them in php:

```
$line = 'var code = [39.474, -0.3548];';

preg_match("/(?:\[)(.*)[,][ ](.*)(?:\])/", $line, $output_array);

print_r ($output_array);
```

The result will be

```
array(
0   =>  [39.474, -0.3548]
1   =>  39.474
2   =>  -0.3548
)
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick and dirty solution may be:

1. Replace "[" and "]"
2. explode by ","

   `$a = "[39.474, -0.3548]";
   $b = str_replace("]", "", str_replace("[", "", $a));
   $c = explode(",", $b);
   print_r($c);`

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 39.474 [1] => -0.3548 )
```