# PHP Parse custom characters inside a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I need a help to parse the characters inside those brackets:

1. `[]`
2. `{}`
3. `<>`
4. `{|}`
5. `<|>`

For example, I have this string variable (Japanese):

`$question = "この<部屋|へや>[に]{椅子|いす}[が]ありません";`

Expected result in HTML:

[image]

### Description

- 1) This is a particle. I will convert all word inside `[]` into HTML tag. Example: `[に]` will be converted into `<span style="color:blue">に</span>`. A full sentence can have multiple `[]`. Note: I understand how to use str_replace.
- 2 and 4) This is normal kanji word which will be used as a question to the user. A full sentence can only have one `{}`.
- 3 and 5) This is normal kanji text. A full sentence can have multiple `{}`.
- 2, 3, 4, and 5) They will converted into Ruby html tags. Sometimes they will not have a `|` separator, which is not mandatory. From what I understand, I just need to explode the `|` characters. If explode return false or `|` not exist, I will use original value. Note: I understand how to use ruby tags (rb and rt).

### My question

How do I parse characters 1-5 I mentioned above with PHP? What keyword I need to start?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @mplungjan str_replace is only usable for description no 1, however, I still need to get a [] wrapper first.

Comment: I'd prob use regexes

Comment: @tam Yes I've found answer by using regexes. I will write the answer.

Comment: Glad u figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this page: [Capturing text between square brackets in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php), now I have my own answer.

Full code:

```
<?php
$text = "この<部屋|へや>[に]{椅子|いす}[が]ありません";
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $square_brackets); //[]
preg_match_all("/{([^}]*)}/", $text, $curly_brackets); //{}
preg_match_all("/<([^}]*)>/", $text, $angle_brackets); //<>

print_r($square_brackets);
echo "\r\n";
print_r($curly_brackets);
echo "\r\n";
print_r($angle_brackets);
echo "\r\n";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [に]
            [1] => [が]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => に
            [1] => が
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {椅子|いす}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 椅子|いす
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <部屋|へや>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 部屋|へや
        )

)
```

Thanks.