# how can i using Regex for find string covered in [ ]?

Tags: php, regex

i have this string

```
<div>
 [select digit "one""two"]
</div>
 [select gender "man""woman"]
```

how can i get just these string [select digit "one""two"] and [select gender "man""woman"]  ?

Comment: i find this \[(.*)\]  but get one string . i needed get string one and two .

Comment: Or a better dup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php.

Comment: @chris85 thanks great .