# How to get specific value from string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the time from the first and second sentence [inside brackets] as below then as result see the differences in a minute. for example, in this case, the result is going to be 1 minute.

```
[04:38:41] Preflight started, flying offline
[04:39:29] Pushing back with 7512 kg of fuel
```

I appreciate if you can help me to find out how I can do this in PHP.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck in parsing the strings, or in calculating the time difference?

Comment: you could use `preg_match()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: Use regex pattern [`/^\[(.*?)\]/`](https://regex101.com/r/pFIZyy/1) to capture times

Comment: Your expected result is wrong..

Comment: @Ashu how can you say that without knowing their business rules?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca result will come in sec which is '48'.. but he mentions it will be 1 minute

Comment: @Ashu and for their business rules that may be ok because it's more than 30 seconds or because it's more than 30 seconds and before 8 AM. We don't know. That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: accepting the correct answer will help to future visitors

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example to get the number of seconds between the two:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('11:01:00');
$datetime2 = strtotime('11:00:01');

echo abs($datetime1-$datetime2);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but you did not mention how I can get the time from the string in first place. That one only change the string to time.

Comment: Check [preg_match_all example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php/10104517). notice that you need to use 'preg_match' instead of 'preg_match_all'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to get the difference in seconds.

```
$string1 = '[04:38:41] Preflight started, flying offline';
$string2 = '[04:39:29] Pushing back with 7512 kg of fuel';

$datetime1 = substr($string1,4,6); // Getting the time of the first string
$datetime2 = substr($string2,4,6); // Getting the time of the second string

echo abs($datetime1-$datetime2); // Calculating the difference between the two values.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$time1 = explode(':', "04:38:41");
$time2 = explode(':', "04:39:29");
echo $result =  $time2[1] - $time1[1];
?>
```

OR, you can do from full texts

```
<?php
$time1_string = "[04:38:41] Preflight started, flying offline";
$time2_string = "[04:39:29] Pushing back with 7512 kg of fuel";
$time1 = explode(':', $time1_string);
$time2 = explode(':', $time2_string);
echo $result =  $time2[1] - $time1[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also achieve your desired result by using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

**Example:**

```
<?php
//string 1
$text1 = '[04:38:41] Preflight started, flying offline';
preg_match('/\\[([^\\]]*)\\]/', $text1, $match);
$time1 = $match[1]; // will return 04:38:41

//string 2
$text2 = '[04:39:29] Pushing back with 7512 kg of fuel';
preg_match('/\\[([^\\]]*)\\]/', $text2, $match);
$time2 = $match[1]; // will return 04:39:29

// check difference
$diff = abs(strtotime($time2) - strtotime($time1));
echo $diff; // will return 48 seconds
?>
```