# How to get string between [ ]

Tags: php, regex

```
$input="[youtube id=HmV4gXIkP6k]";
preg_match_all("~[(.+?)]~",$input,$output);
var_dump($output);
```

how to get string inside [ ]?

Comment: this should help `(?<=\[).*?(?=\])`

Comment: you need to escape the square brackets with double backslash

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104473/capturing-text-between-square-brackets-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the square brackets with a backslash, and as a backslash is also an escape character for PHP string literals, you need to escape the backslash also:

```
$input="[youtube id=HmV4gXIkP6k]";
preg_match_all("~\\[(.+?)\\]~",$input,$output);
var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(24) "[youtube id=HmV4gXIkP6k]"
  }
  [1]=>array(1) {
    [0]=>string(22) "youtube id=HmV4gXIkP6k"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"~\\[(.+?)\\]~"` and `"~\[(.+?)\]~"` and `"~\[(.+?)]~"` define equal regex patterns in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without regular expressions:

```
$Index1 = strpos($input, '[');
$Index2 = strpos($input, ']');
$Result = substr($input, $Index1+1, $Index2-$Index1-1);
```